# Jquery Dialog does not open on mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a simple application on mvc3 with razor before i Open the dialog I tried to open an "alert" and it works correctly so function its working on the event but when i comment this alert and
try to open the dialog it just does not work

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.LogOnModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h2>Index</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'hi there',
            modal: true,

            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
            //alert("entro a funcion");
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });

    });
</script>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Infracciones", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm"}))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Infraccion</legend>

      </fieldset>
    <p>
    <input value="Guardar" type="submit" name = "button"/>
    </p>
}
```

Comment: where is your dialog open statement? where is your dialog body (div)?

Comment: Shows an error in chrome console??

Comment: John paul no error in chorme console

Comment: Dave A. you r the man I forgot that f. div =) thank you

Comment: John paul thank you too =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add this:

```
<div id="dialog">
```

In the body.

Comment: yep and close div too if you want to =)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#dialog').dialog();
```

instead of

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

Comment: As Dave asked, where is your dialog body?